# Anchor-like functionality in Vaadin to jump/scroll to a certain point

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, anchor-scroll

Is there a way in vaadin to scroll or jump to a certain point (e.g. a `Label`) inside a view (e.g. a `Panel`)when a button or link component is clicked? Similar to the anchors functionality on a website?

I'm using Vaadin 7.5.9

**EDIT:**
I have a `HorizontalSplitPanel`. Its first component is a list of items where a user can make a selection. Is an item selected the second component of the `HorizontalSplitPanel` opens. The second component consists of a `VerticalLayout` containing a heading and a menu and a `Panel`. If there is a selection in the menu the `Panel` should be scrolled to the referred entry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's an API on the UI class called [`scrollIntoView(Component)`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#scrollIntoView(com.vaadin.ui.Component)). This is how one calls it

```
private Label result;

public void scrollToResult() {
  UI.getCurrent().scrollIntoView(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It does what I want to achive, but not exactly. I have a `VerticalLayout` in the second component of a `HorizontalSplitPanel`. The `VerticalLayout` contains some content and a `Panel`. Within this `Panel` I want to jump to a certain "anchor". Using your suggested method unfortunately also scrolls the second component of the `HorizontalSplitPane` and not just the content of the `Panel`, which is what I'd like to achieve. Any suggestion for that, please?

Comment: Try to use a `Link` pointing to a fragment, and give the ID to the component via `.setId(String)`

Comment: Do you mean like that?
`Link link = new Link("LinkText", new ExternalResource("#destinationID"));` and for destination component `destComp.setId("destinationID");`?

Because that didn't work for me as my url is similar to `.../start#actualContent`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to solve the issue. I needed to correct my `setExpandRatio` settings

Comment: In later version of Vaadin the `scrollIntoView` method is not present.  Is there a way to do this in newer version of Vaadin?

Answer (score 1):

You can also execute JS code from your Java Vaadin code to scroll to a Component.

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", componentToScrollTo);
```